# Inserting data from dataGridView to the database error

Tags: c#, mysql

The error is

> {Additional information:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ')' at line 1}

This is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    StrQuery = "INSERT INTO 'branch1_orders' VALUES ("
        + order_num + ","
        + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["number"].Value + ","
        + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["price"].Value + ");";
    command.CommandText = StrQuery;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //the error 
}
```

Comment: If you put a break point on StrQuery, what is the SQL that is actually being ran?

Comment: Please add the generated sql query.

Comment: Please use SqlParameter to prevent Sql-Injection! Should order_num be your PK ?

Comment: try adding a whitespace before and after each "," and remove the ";" at the end of the query. If this doesn't work try debugging the code and check the values to see if they are null. Also I don't see any connection connected to this command. that might also be the problem. Let me know if anything of these helped

Comment: @ChrisBint    INSERT INTO 'branch1_orders' VALUES (0,1,20000);      and the data is saved in the database but the error appear

Comment: I reckon that order_num should be the PK ... so after the first insert, you run in your loop in an "duplicate key error"

Comment: I think you need to write table name without quotation marks and if this doesn't work, try to add single quotations to values and check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) to ensure that your query is correct.

Comment: Are all the columns numbers?

Comment: To those suggesting correcting the syntax: Perhaps it would work. But using parameterised queries would be much easier and less error-prone, as well as protecting against SQL injection attacks, which currently the code is completely vulnerable to. Malicious input could easily steal, corrupt or destroy the data as it stands currently, even with the string concatenation "fixed". The MySQL / .NET documentation clearly shows examples of how to use parameterised queries correctly. http://bobby-tables.com/ explains the dangers of the current approach, for those not familiar with it.

Comment: @EssamMohamed w3Schools material is full of errors and incorrect information, all over the place. That particular page you linked to may or may not be, but the site is well known to be a poor resource generally. Better to quote the MySQL documentation, e.g. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html. Also, these values look like (and should be) numeric, so adding quote marks round them will send them as strings, which is not going to work, as well as failing to address the obvious SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the loop it do one more step because the datagradview add a row by it self

the code will be

```
for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView2.Rows.Count)-1; i++)
            {
                StrQuery = "insert into branch1_orders values("
                    + order_num + ","
                    + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["number"].Value + ","
                    + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["price"].Value + ")";
                command.CommandText = StrQuery;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                try
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException e2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e2.Message);
                }
            }
```